# running Rails 3 staging environment locally (404 on all assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2

I'm running my staging server locally using:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rails console -p 1337
```

I have precompiled assets, everything is working fine except I cannot find out how to serve those assets. I have this in my staging.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

In my apache vhost, if I listen on 80, I can access my assets:

```
http://domain.local/assets/application.css
```

But, if I listen on 1337, the same port as my rails server, then rails spits out a 404. My confusion is, I have already told rails not to serve_static_assets, and so why would it try to serve them?

```
http://domain.local:1337/assets/application.css
```

I must be missing something. The site displays fine, just returns 404 on all assets:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-791b26264f9bbe462a28d08cf9a79582.css"):
```

Comment: Do you have the rubyracer gem installed?

Comment: I didn't, but I just installed and it doesn't work with our without it. Could you explain why that could be the issue? I thought rubyracer was for javascript? I've updated with exact error message I receive.

Comment: How does apache fit in? Are you trying to use apache as a reverse proxy? Do you have a ruby module such as phusion passenger installed? What do you get for the contents of `public/assets`?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw The assets are precompiled and are being served if I use apache to listen on port 80. I'm using apache to serve static assets. public/assets contains all assets for my app including application.css. As I say, it resolves fine on 80, but when I use same port as rails server, rails insists on serving the static even after I've specifically told it not to (config.serve_static_assets = false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you access your application through

```
http://domain.local:1337/
```

you are not going through Apache.

If you want to run it using only WEBrick (RAILS_ENV=staging rails s -p 1337), then you should set

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in your staging.rb . That will make WEBrick serve the precompiled assets when you access your application through

```
http://domain.local:1337
```

In order to use the precompiled assets served by Apache you should look into using Apache (or Nginx) in combination with a Ruby module such as Phusion Passenger. Then you will be able to access your app through

```
http://domain.local
```

which will make Apache serve your assets and will forward all other requests to the module. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a read and try to understand the setup more.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as, although I've not figured it out yet, I understand it is due to my own negligence and the clue is somewhere in your answer. In the mean time, I did somehow install and configure unicorn and nginx :)

Comment: That's great. Unicorn is a good choice! Sorry if I was not clear enough. Let me know if I can give you some more help.