# Running Sinatra application on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I have created a Sinatra application, which I want to run on Amazon EC2. I know there is heroku, but having Amazon EC2 as another option would be nice. One other reason is that there is this timeout issue on heroku ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)):

```
The Heroku routing mesh detects and terminates requests taking more than 30 seconds to respond.
```

Up to now I created a micro instance with Ubuntu, and installed required libraries, and got my Sinatra application running by `ruby -rubygems app.rb` command. What I need to do is get my app running all the time, as long as server is running, not just the time between I run the command above and quit the command line. Do you know any simple and lightweight solution to do this?

Comment: Deployment is a very interesting and complicated topic. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options and google "sinatra deployment" and check out some tutorials. There are a few things in this question that leads me to believe you need do some more reading first :).

Answer (score -1):

Install Passenger which is quite easy to setup:

`gem install passenger`

More details and docs see https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download