# requirements for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-hosting

I have made a rails application for a student group. I want to launch the application through the Berkeley Open Computing Facility (OCF). I currently have the app running on Heroku, but the OCF provides storage on the order of GigaBytes, which is more than I can get for free at Heroku.
However, the OCF claims that
 "Ruby 1.8.7 is installed and supported.
Frameworks like Django, Rails, flavor-of-the-month probably work, but are not supported."

Will it be possible to run the app through OCF hosting? Or must the host explicitly support Rails?

Answer (score 0):

The host needs to be able to support some web stack that rails can run under.  This would include [both an HTTP Server (Apache, Nginx, etc) and an Application server (Passenger, Unicorn, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options).  If they have that, and you have permissions to wire up an application - then you can install Rails.

Wiring up the application will involve modifying configuration files and restarting the Application server.  So make sure you (or someone that can help you) has permissions to do so before trying to proceed.