# How can i keep retaining the Amazon EC2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

This is my step

1. Made a new instance in Amazon EC2
2. connect to the ec2 instance with ssh client
3. git cloned a Ruby on Rails app
4. run the server with `rails s`
5. try to connect to the url : EC2PUBLICIP:3000
6. ok it works!
7. closed the ssh client terminal
8. now i cannot connect :(

Do I have to keep retaining the ssh client from my local pc to run the instance server????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rails server &
```

This will run the server in the background, so it will not be stopped when the ssh connection is closed

Comment: yup, i tried that before, but strangly, it doesn't work :( if i reconnect to ssh client and check the process, it is not on the list

Answer (score 0):

For a process to continue after you close the console you need to use [nohup](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/)

```
nohup rails server &
```

But note that if your machine is restarted, there is nothing to start your server automatically. For better production-ready application, look at solutions like the ones mentioned here: [Ruby on Rails Server options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options)