# The best rails server and their configurations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

What is the best choice for development and production server for Rails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Server options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best description was given in the following answer [Ruby on Rails Server options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options) from one of the authors of Phusion Passenger.

There you can find all the neccessary information and much more

Comment: `pry` gem doesn't work fine with `passenger`