# Does phusion passenger use forking, and if so, where to set after_fork config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, passenger, postgis

Does [phusion passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger) use forking? If so, where should I set an `after_fork` configuration, [as recommended by Heroku for unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis#setting-up-postgis-with-rails) (re: Setting up PostGIS with Rails)?

From Heroku's docs:

*Additionally, if unicorn **or any other process forking code** is used where the connection is re-established, make sure to override the adapter to postgis as well. For example:*

```
# unicorn.rb
after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['adapter'] = 'postgis'
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Phusion Passenger does forking, almost exactly like how Unicorn does it. Unicorn's default behavior (`preload_app off`) is the same as Phusion Passenger's "direct spawning" (not default in Phusion Passenger). Unicorn's `preload_app on` is the same as Phusion Passenger's "smart spawning" (default in Phusion Passenger). Sources:

- [passenger_spawn_method documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerSpawnMethod)
- [Appendix C: Spawning methods explained](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#spawning_methods_explained)

The latter also teaches you how to install an after-fork hook.

Answer (score 0):

Phusion Passenger is primarily multi-process; the Enterprise version can do both multi-process and multi-threaded.

- [Ruby on Rails Server options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options)
- http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/12/tuning-phusion-passengers-concurrency-settings/

I don't know if an `after_fork` type thing is needed with Passenger, because it's not Ruby doing the forking of the process, but I'm not 100% sure there.