# Ruby instance connection for Redis

Tags: ruby, redis

In my code to reuse the redis connection across multiple URL route, is this the correct way to define instance for a single threaded in Redis?

```
class Red
    @conn ||= H2O::Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
    class << self
      attr_reader :conn
    end
end


e.g. Route "/set"
    require "/www/test.rb"
    redis = Red.conn
    redis.set(...)

e.g. Route "/get"
    require "/www/test.rb"
    redis = Red.conn
    redis.get(...)
```

Comment: That will work, you can see you're using the same object each time by calling `Red.conn.object_id`

Comment: `require Red` won't work, you need to require a file not a class and also you shouldn't require in the routes, require elsewhere

Comment: @max pleaner, I have edited the code, it's "/www/test.rb" working on MRuby in H2O web server.

Comment: @Anthony There was one suggested implement using "connection pool" libraries, is my code Singleton really suitable for web server environement?

Answer (score 0):

For a single threaded web server running on a single process, absolutely this is the correct way to do it. You will have no issues, as Ruby's GIL ensures no two lines of code will ever run in parallel.

The [question arises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180809/does-phusion-passenger-use-forking-and-if-so-where-to-set-after-fork-config) when you start spawning multiple processes through forking them - as that shares the memory before its modified.
And looking through documentation of some services that do forking, they do recommend you re-establish connections:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/#am-i-responsible-for-reestablishing-database-connections-after-the-preloader-has-forked-a-child-process