# How to make Rails 4 work with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, cpanel

**I have a rails application that I would like to deploy on a Linux-based cloud hosting running on Apache server.**

I have been searching for information online, it seems to me like using Phusion Passenger is an option.

However I have no idea how to set it all up locally and in production. The Linux-based cloud hosting has a cpanel interface. Do I ftp the whole rails folder into the file manager?

**Could someone please guide me or point me to a useful guide with step 1, 2, etc. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Did [this](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options) not help?

Answer (score 0):

**In order to install Passenger on a hosting service you will need SSH access.**

*If it's shared hosting you will most likely not get SSH, I would recommend [www.digitalocean.com](http://www.digitalocean.com) they give you full access to your private server.*

**Here is a guide once you have SSH access:**

https://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid