# How does Rails + (Phusion Passenger|Puma|Unicorn|Thin) + (Nginx|Apache) work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger

When a http request is made, what is the role of the 3 different groups mentioned above? What do each of them do before the Application code is finally called?

Answer (score 2):

At the high-level, the three play the following roles:

### Rails

**Application**. Encompasses the business logic - user management, buy / sell transactions, display / update / delete / create information, etc.

### Passenger

**Application Server**. The server equivalent of running `rails server` locally.

### Apache

**Web/HTTP server**. Intercepts and responds to requests from clients (browsers).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113570/429758 for an in-depth treatment on this topic.