# Ruby on rails as subdomain of an existing webpage based on Joomla

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, joomla, subdomain, hosting

Does anyone see any roadblocks to routing a rails 4 app as a subdomain of an existing website made from Joomla?

Although they are different frameworks, I'm not trying to integrate the two apps.  Just placing two different websites under a single domain.  My thinking is as long as both applications are on the same server and I fixed my namespace in my rails routes file, all should be ok.  Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are no problem, the only 2 things you have to care about are :

- take care of the item menu in joomla
- the ruby web server configuration

**About the joomla item menu.**
In the *Menu Manager* > *Edit Menu Item* as a *Menu Item Type* chose System Links > External Url .
In the Link field you can put your rails url.
With this configuration you can route your user to your rails app.

**About the ruby web server configuration**
Probably you already have your rails app running, so you are not worried about the web server.
But because you already have an Apache server for Joomla I guess It could be interesting for you know that like for php in Apache there is mod_php, for ruby there is [Phusion Passenger](http://www.phusionpassenger.com).

And that's the discussion on Stackoverflow: [Ruby on Rails Server options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113299/ruby-on-rails-server-options)