# Just curious to ask being a newbie in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

Does A rails application runs on any webserver or some particular servers are required to run a rails application. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: I think this link is super info for your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113570/938947

Answer (score 1):

Rails application runs only on [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) based servers like Webrick, Puma, Passenger, Unicorn etc.

Checkout https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-rack-web-servers-for-ruby-web-applications